# Setting objects equal to each other in C++

Tags: c++

How can we set the private members of two objects equal to each other. By that I mean assign the private members of Class2 to Class1 so that when we set up the the objects we can set set them equal to each other.

Comment: Implement `Class1& operator=(const Class2& other);`

Comment: What is the function of other in this? How does that come into play?

Comment: other is the RHS variable of '=' operator. When you use statements like objClass1 = objClass2;, objClass2 gets passed as an argument to operator=() function. Here "other" is just a variable which is a reference to objClass2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using `assignment operator`.

Please find below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
    public:
        B() : y(1) {}
        int getY() const { return y; }
    private:
       int y;
};


class A
{
   public:
      A() : x(0) {}
      void operator=(const B &in)
      {
          x = in.getY();
      }
      void display()
      {
          cout << x << endl;
      }
  private:
      int x;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a = b;
    a.display();
    return 0;
 }
```

I hope it helps!